# How come jQuery can't remove this element?

Tags: jquery, html-table, row

I have a table like this:

```
<table id='inventory_table'>
  <tr id='no_items_avail'>
    <td>
      There are no items in the database.
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And I want to get rid of it with jQuery like this:

```
$('#inventory_table tbody tr#no_items_avail').remove();
```

However it doesn't seem to be working at all. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Also, the row above was originally inserted into the DOM with another jQuery call:

```
$('#inventory_table tbody').append("<tr id='no_items_avail'.......
```

If that helps. And, running:

```
alert($('#no_items_avail').text());
```

yields "There are no items in the database." as expected.

Comment: Well, if `$('#inventory_table tbody').append` worked you should really make sure that you don't have the id=no_items_avail in your document already - it's not allowed to have non-unique IDs and will only cause  headaches. I recommend classes for that.

Comment: Am I allowed to hit my head on the wall? Some complicated reference counting code was hiding the fact that it was recreating the object after it was removed. My bad!

    (Now which answer to select...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are using the same ID more than once in the same document? Because this works perfectly for me on IE8 (compatibility mode), FF and Chrome.

Of course it doesn't need to be that complex as this works perfectly:

```
$("#no_items_avail").remove();
```

Just remember that IDs have to be unique and duplicating them is a common reason why this kind of thing fails.

Comment: As mentioned above in my edit, running "alert($('#no_items_avail').text());" displays the text, demonstrating that jQuery is finding the right element.

Comment: Never mind. See my comment above under the question. Thanks for trying it in your browser.

Comment: Oh my god I love you!  I was trying to remove elements of a certain class like $("#parent").remove(".childType1"),$("#parent").remove(".childType2") and so on. Diddly squat happened. Changed it to $("#parent .childType1").remove() and things were smooth sailing. I say it is BS that using the same selector repeatedly doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

You assume `tbody` to be available in your DOM. Only a few browsers add `tbody` to a table if it does not exist. Try

```
$('#inventory_table tr#no_items_avail').remove();
```

or even better

```
$('#no_items_avail').remove();
```

(since IDs must be unique anyway).

Comment: Now it does. And simplifying the selector was a good idea anyway. +1 for that.

Comment: What browsers don't add implicit `<tbody>` elements?

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is unnecessary large. This is shorter and it works:
    $('#no_items_avail').remove();​​​​​

Also, make sure you have no other elements with same `id`.

Comment: I don't have any other elements with the same id.

Answer (score 0):

Try using dash '-' in your ids instead of underscore. I believe some browsers don't react well to underscores. Maybe I'm thinking about CSS instead of JS but give it a try for what it's worth.

Comment: Thanks but it's fixed now. See above.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector references a non-existant tbody:

```
$('#inventory_table tbody tr#no_items_avail').remove();
```

Remove 'tbody' and it should work:

```
$('#inventory_table tr#no_items_avail').remove();
```

Alternately, just reference the tr ID itself:

```
$('#no_items_avail').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no `<tbody>` tag in the table. The jQuery selection "stops" after not finding it.

Answer (score -2):

1) Don't use IDs to identify stuff with jQuery, use classes or possibly path-based selection.
2) Don't add and remove content, show and hide it instead.

Dynamically changing your page content in arbitrary ways is not going to help maintainability, so I hope what you're doing well disciplined, in some way, and well documented.  Think of the poor sod who will have to take over when you get hit by a bus or win the lottery.

Comment: Why would you possibly tell someone to not use ids to select? Selection by ID is the FASTEST possible method, and maps directly to javascript's `getElementById`

Comment: The use of IDs everywhere can be a sign of spaghetti code in which the overall design is very closely tied to accidental details of the implementation, making the result harder to change, to generalize, to reapply.  Of course there isn't always a need for that, and it's just a rule of thumb anyway.

Comment: You may find this article useful: http://www.tizag.com/cssT/cssid.php. IDs are invaluable, and should be used to identify unique page elements. Classes are used for elements which may be repeated.

Comment: @George Cummins: I knew this before CSS existed.  Feel free to disagree with what I wrote, but don't assume it's based on a lack of understanding of what ID is for.